# jsQR Javascript mediadevices undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, navigator, mediadevices

I am trying to implement the jsQR javascript library from git: [jsQR](https://github.com/cozmo/jsQR)

I am testing on Safari 13.0.4 and when i run their demo found on their webpage it runs with no problems.

Now when i implement the same exact code (copy&paste) from the demo's inspector to my page i get the message `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia')` which after some console printing the actual undefined object is `navigator.mediaDevices` this is strange since their demo is working i do not think it is a browser issue.

Additionally i run my page on firefox and it works perfectly fine.

What might be the problem?

Here is the code i have (it is the exact as demo anyway):

Javascript:

```
var video = document.createElement("video");
var canvasElement = document.getElementById("canvas");
var canvas = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
var loadingMessage = document.getElementById("loadingMessage");
var outputContainer = document.getElementById("output");
var outputMessage = document.getElementById("outputMessage");
var outputData = document.getElementById("outputData");

function drawLine(begin, end, color) {
    canvas.beginPath();
    canvas.moveTo(begin.x, begin.y);
    canvas.lineTo(end.x, end.y);
    canvas.lineWidth = 4;
    canvas.strokeStyle = color;
    canvas.stroke();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log(navigator.mediaDevices);
})

// Use facingMode: environment to attemt to get the front camera on phones
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { facingMode: "environment" } }).then(function(stream) {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.setAttribute("playsinline", true); // required to tell iOS safari we don't want fullscreen
    video.play();
    requestAnimationFrame(tick);
});

function tick() {
    loadingMessage.innerText = "⌛ Loading video..."
    if (video.readyState === video.HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA) {
        loadingMessage.hidden = true;
        canvasElement.hidden = false;
        outputContainer.hidden = false;

        canvasElement.height = video.videoHeight;
        canvasElement.width = video.videoWidth;
        canvas.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
        var imageData = canvas.getImageData(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
        var code = jsQR(imageData.data, imageData.width, imageData.height, {
            inversionAttempts: "dontInvert",
        });
        if (code) {
            drawLine(code.location.topLeftCorner, code.location.topRightCorner, "#FF3B58");
            drawLine(code.location.topRightCorner, code.location.bottomRightCorner, "#FF3B58");
            drawLine(code.location.bottomRightCorner, code.location.bottomLeftCorner, "#FF3B58");
            drawLine(code.location.bottomLeftCorner, code.location.topLeftCorner, "#FF3B58");
            outputMessage.hidden = true;
            outputData.parentElement.hidden = false;
            outputData.innerText = code.data;
        } else {
            outputMessage.hidden = false;
            outputData.parentElement.hidden = true;
        }
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(tick);
}
```

Html:

```
 <div id="loadingMessage"> Unable to access video stream (please make sure you have a webcam enabled)</div>
    <canvas id="canvas" hidden></canvas>
    <div id="output" hidden>
        <div id="outputMessage">No QR code detected.</div>
        <div hidden><b>Data:</b> <span id="outputData"></span></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The development server is not secure and thus safari does not allow the use of WebRTC on insecure connections.

To allow the use (on safari at least) you have to go to Develop>WebRTC>Allow media capture on insecure sites.